# MapKit.framework linking error

Tags: mapkit, ios10, xcode8

Strange error happening on Xcode 8 with iOS 10. An app uses MapKit. I was working with simulator and all was fine. And I wanted to run on a device.
And I was getting these errors. After that, I restarted my Mac, and now I'm unable to run even on simulator.

OSX: El Capitan,
Xcode 8,
iOS 10

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked your build phase ? Does it have MapKit framework included ? Based on error it seems like you have an extra '(' or missing ')' somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Check your Project's Capabilities and turn Map - ON.
Check Your Build Phases if you have MapKit framework imported.
If you already have the framework try to remove and re add .

Good luck :)